# Algorithm to detect an image in another image with some noise

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, ocr, detection

I'm searching for the best library to search for identical area in two different images, all images being compressed in JPEG, with a lot of noise. I'm having a hard time finding one. The problem is if you zoom a jpeg, you'll see that it looks like a Monet, I mean, the noise contains a color palette that have no direct link with the original image. So instead of searching for an identical array in the image, I need to find the 'most similar array'.

These images come from random screenshot over a googlemap similar websites, and the images cannot be in another format than jpeg.

I tried a lot of manual way.

One of my method is:

Transforming my two images in smaller images

Changing them in 4bpp images, or even less colors

Taking a small part of image 1

Searching for the byte[] array version of a cropped part of image 1 in image 2

Not searching for identical, but for similar matches.

This algorithm works, but I'm doing everything in one dimension array, and it is very slow.

Is there existing libraries that would do this algorithm directly?

My algorithm is:

```
    // Where SRC is the bigger image in which I search
    // Offset is where in my small image I start to search
    // Len is how long is my searched array
    // Size is the size of the bigger image in which I'm searching.
    // private Point simpleSearch(byte[] src, int offset, int len, byte[] search, Size size)
    {
        byte[] ddd = new byte[len];
        Array.Copy(search, offset, ddd, 0, len);
        int lowest = 100000000;
        int locmatch = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < src.Length - len; i++)
        {
            int thed = 0;
            for (int a = 0; a < len; a++)
            {
                int diff = Math.Abs(src[i + a] - ddd[a]);
                thed += diff;
            }

            thed = thed / len;
            if (thed < lowest)
            {
                lowest = thed;
                locmatch = i-len;
            }
        }

        int yy = (locmatch / size.Width);
        int xx = locmatch - (yy * size.Width);
        Point p = new Point(xx, yy);
        return p;
    }
```

Comment: what about translation/rotation/scale invariance?

Comment: Sorry, I was in my developer little bubble. These are screenshots taken randomly on a map similar to google map, so translation change, rotation doesn't change, scale doesn't change.

Comment: Two-dimensional cross-correlation?  I think that can even be accelerated using a 2-D FFT.

Comment: Wow, very good advice. Thank you. If you can put it as an answer, I'll accept it since I understand what you mean.

Comment: Anyway, I know all other answers will be about EmguCV

Comment: Correlation would probably be what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep correlation or spectrum signature are ways to tell how similar two image regions are. But I think what you really want here is an algorithm to **efficiently search the overlapping region**.

[Correspondence problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_problem) is a well defined problem in computer vision that tries to figure out which parts of an image correspond to which parts of another image. There are [RANSAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC) based algorithms.

There's also [a quad-tree algorithm](http://www.iaeng.org/publication/WCE2010/WCE2010_pp687-691.pdf) that brings the complexity down to logarithm order.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the direct link to the algorithm. I was thinking about something similar to quad-tree algorithm. You start with a very small image, then at each step, zoom on the more similar image. With your answer, I should do something that works.